# Scoping rules (LEGB) in Python with if-else statement

Tags: java, python, scope

In Python, if I create and initialize a variable inside a `if-else` statement, the variable will be visible after the `if-else` statement ends.

```
a = 33

if a % 2 == 0:
    is_even = True
else:
    is_even = False

print(f'{a} is even? {is_even}')
```

Since `is_even` is created inside `if` and `else`, why is it visible after the `if-else` block? For example, in Java, attempting to do the same will not work.

```
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 33;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      boolean isEven = true;
    } else {
      boolean isEven = false;
    }

    System.out.println(a + " is even? " + isEven); // isEven cannot be resolved
  }
}
```

The only way to get `isEven` to be visible after the `if-else` statement is to declare it outside.

```
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 33;
    boolean isEven;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      isEven = true;
    } else {
      isEven = false;
    }

    System.out.println(a + " is even? " + isEven);
  }
}
```

I've read bout the [LEGB](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) rules, but, I'm not sure how that explains, in Python, how `is_even` is visible outside of the blocks in which it was declared.

Any clarification on this non-understanding?

Comment: It is just a design decision to have only a few namespaces (and therefore simpler rules) in Python.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, Java and Python are two very different languages and they have different rules.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok, but, is LEGB at play at all here? Coming from the Java mothership, scopes are controlled via curly braces `{}`, and it's most desirable to consider the block operator `:` as a sort of an analogy to `{}`.

Comment: @NomadMaker If this scoping behavior is a rule or design, is there official documentation on it? I have to find a coherent way to explain this to myself and others.

Comment: @JaneWayne Java has such a document on Oracle's site. Python's web site might have such a documentation for Python.

Comment: Java braces can't be compared in this aspect with a Python block which just helps to control the flow of execution. Python namespaces are created only by some language constructs like function definition or class definition (the latter in a different way as Java, too).

Answer (score 1):

Python knows three main blocks (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program):

- a module
- a function body
- and a class definition

The main difference to Java is this:

- in Java the curly braces after an `if` / `else` (etc) statement also define a block
- in Python the statements following `if ():` and `else:` (etc) only form a "suite" of statements (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html), never a block